# How to use raw array as a list in memory mapped file C++

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-mapped-files

```
struct Disc
{
char cName[1024];
DWORD dSize;
}
```

In my code CreateFileMapping(..) is used to create a memory mapped file object for this structure.

```
m_mmf = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,
                0,
                PAGE_READWRITE,
                0,
                sizeof(Disc),
                "Disc_mmf");
```

I want to share list of string information across the processes so wanted to have this list
in this Disc structure so that it can be a part of memory mapped file and can be shared across the process. I know we cant include `std::list<std::string>` in memory mapped file as it contains pointers to unmapped portions of the memory. How to add list of string in Disc structure
by use of raw arrays to deal with raw memory?

Comment: You probably need some synchronization method to prevent a data race

Comment: What have your text-books taught you about arrays, and how arrays and *pointers* are related?

Comment: Write the length of the string first, then write the characters of the string to the memory map. On the other side, read the length, then read length characters into a buffer of that size. TLDR: Serialization. Use some IPC synchronization method to make sure it is safe to read or write. On windows you can use CreateEvent or even a Mutex with global namespace. In WinAPI, you also don't need a physical file. You can map paged memory and it will be available globally.

Comment: My question here is how to replicate std::list<std::string> in Disc structure in form of array of strings . And while adding to array of strings I don't want to iterate a loop. Hope my question is clear.

Comment: Perhaps use a structure with a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member). The store the `size` member as the first member. Then to get to the next array element cast the pointer to the structure into a pointer to a byte, add the size of the string plus the size of the structure, and you get a byte pointer to the next structure which you can then cast back into a pointer to your structure. Unless you want to store actual pointers in the structure (which point to the shared memory of course) to treat it like an actual linked list.

Comment: Also, for better performance you need to think about things like alignment and padding between array elements as well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You can't store pointers in shared memory, since the pointers will have different meanings in each process. But you can store offsets instead. Store the list as a flat array in the shared memory, where each structure contains an offset to the next structure in the shared memory. Then each process can have its own pointer to the shared memory and apply the offsets to that pointer to access each structure as needed.

Comment: Could you show me in examples how to achieve this?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yeah offsets, right. That's what I meant I think. :)

Comment: [Why double-null-terminated strings instead of an array of pointers to strings?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110511-00/?p=10693)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude could you please show me in an example for better understanding ?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am not aware of how to Store the list as a flat array. Could you please guide me with an example?